# Freemarker iterate ArrayList of Objects and access a variable?

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, freemarker

I have the following POJO class:

```
public final class Item
{
    public final long id;
    public final String hash;

    public Item(long _id, String _hash)
    {
        id = _id;
        hash = _hash;
    }
}
```

I have an `ArrayList<Item>`:

```
ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Item(1, "abc"));
list.add(new Item(2, "def"));
```

The list is added to the template:

```
MODEL.addAttribute("history_list", list);
```

The template successfully iterates through the list the number of times that an item was inserted but fails to get the property of the individual item:

```
<#list history_list as row>
     <p>${row.hash}</p>
<#else>
     no items here
</#list>
```

**The error:**
    The following has evaluated to null or missing:
    ==> row.hash [in template "history.ftl" at line 9, column 69]

Why?

Comment: Did you try it with a getter? I thought FM relied on the JavaBean spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was such a [mail list request](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/Access-to-public-feilds-td624997.html) to allow access to public fields
The solution is to use method `setExposeFields`

```
DefaultObjectWrapper wrapper = new DefaultObjectWrapper(); 
wrapper.setExposeFields(true); 
FreeMarkerCfg.setObjectWrapper(wrapper);
```

This is explained in [freemarker docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html)

> If you call `setExposeFields(true)` on a BeansWrapper instance, it will also expose public, non-static fields of classes as hash keys and values. I.e. if foo is a public, non-static field of the class Bar, and bar is a template variable wrapping an instance of Bar, then `bar.foo` expression will evaluate as the value of the field foo of the bar object. The public fields in all superclasses of the class are also exposed.

Answer (score 1):

For Readers

**Also make sure your class is public**. I wasted my 3 hours after adding `wrapper.setExposeFields(true);` from @user7294900 answer.

Freemarker does Not read or access Public variables/methods of a Private class and Private variables/methods of a public class.